# I want to know a different approach for an integration problem

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

[The Question is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2dYh.png)

So now in this question we can multiply the denominator and numeriator by the conjugate 1-cosx and that also solves the problem and the answer comes out to be (-cotx + cosecx +C) , where C is the constant.

But in the question the solution is given in some different form (tan x/2... something like that)
I can't think of the approach to get this answer, Can anyone help?

And Sorry I'm new to this platform So I don't know how to write mathematical equations, Highly Appreciated if anyone can teach me how to do so (I'm using a mobile).

Comment: $cos(2A)=2cos(A)^2-1$ should do it.

Comment: [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) the tutorial of writing mathematical expressions on this site.